# How to get eid from table which is having max number of count in the Mid?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table employee which is having following structure:

```
Id.      Mid    Salary

1          20        200
2          20       3000
3         30       200
4         34       4000
5        30         300
6        30        400
1        23        440
1        24         333
2         21        3
```

I want to get result like:

```
Id     Mid
1      3
```

Comment: So you want the most frequent id and the number of times it appears in the table?

Comment: Can you explain why `3`?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: 3 will be the count of mid corresponding to id 1.

Comment: #zohar peled yes you are right?

Answer (score 1):

use top 1

```
select top 1 id,count(*) as cnt
from table   
group by id
order by cnt desc
```

if you need ties then use `with ties`

```
select top 1 with ties id,count(*) as cnt
    from table   
    group by id
    order by cnt desc
```

Comment: If multiple  ids have the same count in that case top 1 will display 1 id only

Comment: @mahadevdhyani yes it will show 1 id but if you need all then you have to use ties

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - using `top with ties` and aggregation

```
select top 1 with ties  id, count(mid) as Mid
from table
group by id
order by count(mid) desc
```